# iOS Unwind Segue stops working when embedded in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

I have a UIViewController which has a button that performs a modal segue to a UIViewController as a Form Sheet.  On that form sheet is a cancel button with an unwind segue back to the original UIViewController.  This seems to work perfectly happily and dismisses the form sheet.

As soon as I select the original UIViewController and select the option in XCode to Embed in a Navigation Controller, the unwind segue no longer seems to work and the modal form sheet will no longer cancel.

I'm sure there is a simple explanation, but it is currently evading me, so any thoughts welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know why you get the behavior you're seeing, I see it too. It happens for both the page sheet and form sheet presentations, but not for full screen. However, the unwind segue is still calling the method you put in the original controller (the one you connected the unwind segue to). So, all you need to do is put a line in that method:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, that does work... Very odd behaviour though right given it works fine for full screen?  Thank you.

Comment: @Darren, yeah, this seems like a bug to me. I couldn't find any documentation that would indicate this is intended behavior.

Comment: I'm also seeing this on ios 8.2 with an ipad retina simulator. IMO this is a bug

Comment: Bug still present in Xcode 6.3.1... Also present in iPhone 6 Plus in landscape... Sth to do with size classes. More info here: https://openradar.appspot.com/20707045

Comment: FINALLY I've been looking for this answer all day!! This is my exact problem with exact behavior.

Comment: @Mike - indeed. if the above does not work, see the workaround below from me

Comment: This appears to be fixed in 9.3 at least.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered, but the above did not give me the full solution, so i thought i would share mine.

For me the unwind method was never called, so i could not do what was described above. Instead i made a simple button with an IBAction and called it. Swift example below:

```
@IBAction func cancelToRecipeController() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    print("cancel to recipe controller ran")
}
```

Thanks to @rdelmar above for the method call!

(This was added for ios 9)

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

"dismiss" didn't work for me but popToRoot works well.

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```